# How to limit the bandwidth when uploading large files to azure blob storage using go?

Tags: azure, go, azure-blob-storage, bandwidth, bandwidth-throttling

I'm using [azblob](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob) package to upload large video files to azure blob using go.

I have multiple video files with large file size for upload. I'm triggering go routines to upload files concurrently to azure blob storage.

The issue here is, this program will take most of the (or all) bandwidth for uploading videos. I can't use other services that requires internet (or it might be slow).

Is there any possible way to limit the rate of bandwidth (**bandwidth throttling**) used for uploading videos in go?

does `azblob` package have any approach to limit bandwidth for uploading videos?

When I'm using other cloud platforms like, AWS or GCP do I need to find this solution for respective packages or is there any solution that is common for limiting bandwidth in go?

Comment: usually this kind of thing would be accomplished at the with QoS (Quality of Service) which, being at OS level and not application level, can help balance bandwith allocation across applications.

Comment: @erik258 What if I'm going to give this application to a client and How can I assume that the client's operating system have all these bandwidth throttling? Will it not be considered as a flaw of my application if it takes all the bandwidth of the client?

Comment: how is your application supposed to be aware of how it affects other programs' traffic?